# jQuery get faded element in fadeIn callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein

Is there a way to get the element, that I faded, in the callback of a `fadeIn`? So far i tried $(this) and it does not work, returns document...

Example, here I need access to the `class="row"` div that I added.

```
 $('<div class="row allow-drag id=' + id + '"></div>').hide().insertAfter(e.target).fadeIn(600, () => {
    console.log($(this));
});
```

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) do not bind it's own 'this' context.

Use a normal function declaration and it will work.